# How do I avoid creating a cross product when extracting multiple sub-elements from a list in JQ?

Tags: json, jq, cross-product

I'm getting product information from a vendor. It's got a bajillion fields in it, but I have this trimmed down to just relevant fields. I'm anticipating the solution has something to do with `map()`, but I just haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

When I try and get multiple fields out of a sub-dictionary, it does a cross product. I'm expecting 2 lines back in this example, but I get 4.

[Fiddle](https://jqplay.org/s/i-H4zXDGvY)
Expected output:

```
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_A",
  "img_angle": "ViewA"
}
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_B",
  "img_angle": "ViewB"
}
```

---

Starting data:

```
{
  "Products": [
    {
      "SKU": "1234",
      "Description": "Pink Ring",
      "RingSize": 7,
      "Images": [
        {
          "FullUrl": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_A",
          "SortOrder": 1,
          "Angle": "ViewA"
        },
        {
          "FullUrl": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_B",
          "SortOrder": 2,
          "Angle": "ViewB"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I then pass it through this filter:

```
.Products[] | { sku: .SKU, desc: .Description, img_url: .Images[].FullUrl, img_angle: .Images[].Angle }
```

This gives me the following data:

```
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_A",
  "img_angle": "ViewA"
}
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_A",
  "img_angle": "ViewB"
}
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_B",
  "img_angle": "ViewA"
}
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_B",
  "img_angle": "ViewB"
}
```

This is what I'm hoping for. You can see URL_A and ANGLE_A don't cross multiply with URL_B and ANGLE_B.

```
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_A",
  "img_angle": "ViewA"
}
{
  "sku": "1234",
  "desc": "Pink Ring",
  "img_url": "https://provider.com/rings/1234_B",
  "img_angle": "ViewB"
}
```

Please don't assume that you can trust `img_url` and `img_angle` to have values that reference each other - you definitely can't, that's only here for illustration purposes.

I've tried several things that keep giving me a cross product and don't actually change the output, like `{ sku: .SKU, desc: .Description } + { img_url: .Images[].FullUrl } + { img_angle: .Images[].Angle }`.

I've also tried adapting recipes from [this recipe book](https://remysharp.com/drafts/jq-recipes) and [this cheat sheet](https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/jq). I haven't been able to get anything useful that doesn't puke at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
.Products[] | {sku: .SKU, desc: .Description} + (
  .Images[] | {img_url: .FullUrl, img_angle: .Angle}
)
```

[Fiddle](https://jqplay.org/s/nRHCkn0we_)

Comment: Yes! Exactly that. Thank you so much! That both gets me the answer and helps me understand wtf is going on here. Mucho gracias!

Answer (score 2):

You can see `STREAM as $var` as creating a foreach loop.

```
.Products[] |
.Images[] as $img |
{ sku: .SKU, desc: .Description, img_url: $img.FullUrl, img_angle: $img.Angle }
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/ufjQz207JY)

---

We can show this is equivalent to other answer.

Let's start by factoring out `$img`.

```
.Products[] |
.Images[] as $img |
{ sku: .SKU, desc: .Description } +
( $img | { img_url: .FullUrl, img_angle: .Angle } )
```

Now we can inline the variable because 1) it's only used once and 2) the topic (`.`) is the same.

```
.Products[] |
{ sku: .SKU, desc: .Description } +
( .Images[] | { img_url: .FullUrl, img_angle: .Angle } )
```

And we're already there.