# Parsing json values and converting them to csv using jq

Tags: shell, jq

I need your help for parsing below json file and converting them to csv using jq command.

```
  {
        "id": 15,
        "description": "package",
        "active": true,
        "name": "linux",
        "project": [
        {
            "id": 1762,
            "description": "This Red Hat Server 7 is built from the Redhat Official",
            "path": "x86_24",
            "url": "some url"
        },
        {
            "id": 1663,
            "description": "This Ubuntu 20.04 is built from the Ubuntu Official",
            "path": "x86_24",
            "url": "some url"
        },
        {
            "id": 1557,
            "description": "This Centos 7 is built from the Centos Official",
            "path": "x86_24",
            "url": "some url"
        }
    ]
    }
    {
        "id": 22,
        "description": "exe",
        "active": true,
        "name": "windows",
        "project": []
    }
    {
        "id": 34,
        "description": "brew",
        "active": true,
        "name": "mac",
        "project": []
    }
```

The values which I need from this json is: id, description, project.id, project.description, project.url. I tried doing with jq cmd, but at last my csv is getting messed up. Here id holds project, project has multiple ids. I need to separate them and generate my csv like below. I'm stuck up here. Any solution for this ? Thanks in Advance !

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```sh
jq -r '
  [.id, .description] + (.project[] | [.id, .description, .url])
  | @csv
'
```

```
15,"package",1762,"This Red Hat Server 7 is built from the Redhat Official","some url"
15,"package",1663,"This Ubuntu 20.04 is built from the Ubuntu Official","some url"
15,"package",1557,"This Centos 7 is built from the Centos Official","some url"
22,"exe",1332,"This Windows 7 is developed from the Windows Official","some url"
22,"exe",1563,"This Windows 11 is developed from the Windows Official","some url"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B1zZJQ8BCY)

---

You can also adopt @ikegami's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69973010/how-do-i-avoid-creating-a-cross-product-when-extracting-multiple-sub-elements-fr/69991026#69991026) to a (technically) very similar problem:

```sh
jq -r '
  .project[] as $p
  | [.id, .description, $p.id, $p.description, $p.url]
  | @csv
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/T-3SGYpWd1)

Comment: If you want to include a header row, simply prepend it as an array of strings and a final comma like so `["id", "description", "project_id", "project_description", "project_url"], `.

Comment: For a header row in the alternative solution, another parenthesis is required: `[...], (...) | @csv`.

Comment: Hey.. this is what I'm looking for.. Thanks a lot ! But, I dont want that id (15,22) to get repeated.. Anyway to remove them alone using jq ? (not project id).. Let me know if I'm not clear

Comment: I need your help on this scenario.. sometimes my project will be null "project": []. At that time, my id and description should get printed. cmd which you shared is not working in this scenario..

    {
        "id": 22,
        "description": "exe",
        "active": true,
        "name": "windows",
        "project": []
    }

Comment: Actually, CSV as a *data construct* doesn't work that way. But a *custom formatting* is no problem for `jq`. Can you post your desired output in **text format** so that I can see what exactly should happen with your sample data? (Maybe you want empty fields to maintain the overall number of fields, which is 5, or maybe you want them missing entirely, giving you only the number of fields that have changed, or ... something else).

Comment: Regarding the case where `.project` is `null` (or rather, as in your example, an **empty array** `[]`), please include this case in your **textually formatted** desired output so that I can see what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey.. I just edited my question by making some change in json and desired output pic. Hope it explains you more.. Let me know if I'm not clear

Comment: `jq` does not output pictures. Please provide a **textual representation**. There are a dozen ways to interpret your picture in text format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239312/discussion-between-gamer-rulez-and-pmf).